# Gene Sequencing and Plasmapper

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, dna-sequencing

Is there anything similar to [this](http://www.addgene.org/browse/sequence/13846/) in Java (especially the circular map sequencing along with hover effect)? 
For information I would like to convey that I am using Plasmapper and BioJava for achieving this, but, as the output is in image format, so I am not able to achieve the above said requirement.
Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Check these out. They provide the functionality that you want:

- [ApE](http://biologylabs.utah.edu/jorgensen/wayned/ape/)
- [SnapGene viewer](http://www.snapgene.com/products/snapgene_viewer/)

Comment: Thanks, but I need a web version of this so that I could be able to implement it with in the code (Java Code).

Comment: @AbhijeetKumar. You can try using plasmapper then. It outputs svg. You can perhaps employ some libraries from d3.js for what you want.